# MacintoshHD inside Volumes inside MacintoshHD inside Volumes inside...?

Tags: bash, macos

I'm new to bash, I come from a windows background. I am having trouble understanding why the following occurs:

I can navigate to the root using `cd /`. Makes sense. I then `ls` to see possible directories. I can see `Volumes` listed. I `cd` to `Volumes`. I can `ls` here and see `Macintosh HD`. Okay, so I `cd` to there.

Now, if I `ls`, I can see `Volumes` again? So I go inside that and `Macintosh HD` is in there. Huh? I can go as far as I like: `/volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes...`

Can someone explain why these directories are infinitely nested within each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type `ls -la` inside the `/Volumes/` u can see:

```
Macintosh HD -> /
```

It is a symbolic link to `/`. `/Volumes/` directory contain all mounted volumes on your Mac OS X.

So when you go to `/` you can see `Volumes` and inside that there is a `Macintosh HD` which in turn is a symbolic link to `/`.

The behaviour you see is due to [symbolic link recursion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79571/symbolic-link-recursion-what-makes-it-reset).